# How to get the value of a child attribute in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="menu_item_variant" id="date" onmouseover="mouseIn(this.id)" onmouseout="mouseOut(this.id)">
  <a href="dating-advice.html">Dating Coaching &amp; Advice</a>
</div>
```

hi, could some one help me get the value of `href` using `document.getElementById("date")` etc. thanks ! Andy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the "date" element and then loop through its children:

```
var elm, href;
elm = document.getElementById("date");
for (elm = elm.firstChild; elm; elm = elm.nextSibling) {
    if (elm.nodeName === "A") {
        href = elm.href;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or actually, I think just about every browser has `getElementsByTagName` now, so:

```
var list, href;
list = document.getElementById('date').getElementsByTagName('a');
if (list.length > 0) {
    href = list[0].href;
}
```

More to explore:

- [DOM2 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/) (nearly universally supported)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/) (widely supported)
- [DOM3 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/) (reasonably supported, but gaps in older browsers, particularly IE)
- [HTML5 DOM interfaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-dom-interfaces.html#common-dom-interfaces) (reasonably supported, as they mostly document DOM2 HTML and things browsers vendors were doing -- but test for gotchas)
- [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) and [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org) -- handy places for checking which browsers support what technologies

Comment: @Buts - Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Use `elem.children[0].href`.

If there may be other children before the `<a>`, you can write `elem.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href`

Comment: `firstChild` looks like a whitespace text element to me.

Answer (score 1):

Using document.getElementById(), you can do this:

```
document.getElementById("date").getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#combinators) in combination with  [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```js
const href = document.querySelector('#date a').href;  // or e.g. '#date [href]'
console.log(href)
```

```html
<!-- OP's example -->
<div class="menu_item_variant" id="date" onmouseover="mouseIn(this.id)" onmouseout="mouseOut(this.id)">
  <a href="dating-advice.html">Dating Coaching &amp; Advice</a>
</div>
```